# Can AWS Batch run Windows Docker containers?

Tags: amazon-web-services, batch-file

To Developer,

I have windows exe's that can be put in Docker containers.
Can AWS Batch run Windows Docker containers?
The AWS docs don't seem to identify this as an option.

Thanks,
Marc

Comment: Are you read this https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/creating-a-simple-fetch-and-run-aws-batch-job/

Answer (score 2):

As per the AWS Documentation, AWS Batch does not have support for Windows Compute Environment.

Here is the link to AWS documentation:

> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/batch/latest/userguide/create-batch-ami.html

Under -> **To create a custom compute resource AMI**

1. Choose a base AMI to start from. The base AMI must use HVM virtualization, and it cannot be a Windows AMI.

Comment: is this the same in 2020?

Comment: @gurusai yes it is

Comment: what needs to do to run the windows container image in AWS Batch?

Answer (score 0):

As of 2nd Aug 2023, Windows-based containers are now supported on AWS Batch.

Ref: [What's new article for AWS Batch](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2023/08/aws-batch-fargate-linux-arm64-windows-x86-containers-console/#:%7E:text=AWS%20Batch%20now%20supports%20Linux,containers%20in%20Fargate%20compute%20environments.)

Hooray!

Answer (score -2):

From AWS documentation: no it can not and is not an option.

Comment: Link to documentation source and are there any plans for updates.